# Get last path part from NSString

Tags: iphone, nsstring

Hi all i want extract the last part from string which is a four digit number '03276' i:e `http://www.abc.com/news/read/welcome-new-gig/03276`

how can i do that.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can also use

```
NSString *sub = [@"http://www.abc.com/news/read/welcome-new-gig/03276" lastPathComponent];
```

Comment: Finally a useful string function!

Comment: hi @Pierre, why did you used 'lastPathComponent'? What it means?

Comment: @Adela i used it, because it is a method of NSString that does exactly what was asked. And, of course, it is easier to use method the API provides than to write your own logic. and means exactly what the name says. It return you the last component of a path. Have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/lastPathComponent for some examples of strings and the return value.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Pierre .

Answer (score 28):

If you know how many characters you need, you can do something like this:

```
NSString *string = @"http://www.abc.com/news/read/welcome-new-gig/03276";
NSString *subString = [string substringFromIndex:[string length] - 5];
```

If you just know that it's the part after the last slash, you can do this:

```
NSString *string = @"http://www.abc.com/news/read/welcome-new-gig/03276";
NSString *subString = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] lastObject];
```

Answer (score 5):

Since *nix uses the same path separators as URL's this will be valid as well.

```
[@"http://www.abc.com/news/read/welcome-new-gig/03276" lastPathComponent]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know the length of the number, and it's not gonna change, it can be as easy as:

```
NSString *result = [string substringFromIndex:[string length] - 4];
```

Answer (score 3):

If the last part of the string is always the same length (5 characters) you could use this method to extract the last part:

```
- (NSString *)substringFromIndex:(NSUInteger)anIndex
```

Use the length of the string to determine the start index.

Something like this:

```
NSString *inputStr = @"http://www.abc.com/news/read/welcome-new-gig/03276";
NSString *newStr = [inputStr substringFromIndex:[inputStr length]-5];
NSLog(@"These are the last five characters of the string: %@", newStr);
```

(Code not tested)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = @"http://www.abc.com/news/read/welcome-new-gig/03276";  
NSArray *arr = [str componentSeparatedBy:@"gig/"];  
NSString *strSubStringDigNum = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
```

**strSubStringDigNum** will have the value 03276

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *myUrl = @"http://www.abc.com/news/read/welcome-new-gig/03276";

NSString *number = [[myUrl componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"] objectAtIndex: 5];
```

Comment: By using objectAtIndex:5 you are making sure it works ONLY in that specific address, if the address changes to something like http://www.abc.com/news/read/welcome-new-gig/SOMETHING/03276, it breaks it.