# ios - getting part of an NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, substring

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440187/get-substring-from-nsstring) that talks about getting the last part of a NSString.

I require a slight variation on this.

How do I get everything after the http://

Would be good if it was almost as simple as 1 line of code:-)

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"http://www.abc.com/news/read/welcome-new-gig/03276";

str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://"
                                 withString:@""];
```

hope this will help you.....

Comment: Thank you - you where first so I will accept your answer when I can. (SO requires me to wait another 6 minutes)

Answer (score 1):

`substringFromIndex:`. You'd be wise to do some bounds checking too. Also, I'd advice taking a look at the documentation before asking a question.

Comment: This is a better answer than those that rely on stringByReplacingOccuranceOfString, which replaces ALL instances of the string rather than just the initial instance. Use Benedict Cohen's answer with something like [str substringFromIndex:@"http://".length] to be sure that you don't experience these side effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *originalString = @"http://google.com";
NSString *substring = [originalString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"http://" withString:@""];
```

Answer (score 0):

May want to actually check that you are using "http://" at the front and not replace it in every instance.  How about this:

```
if([[str substringToIndex:@"http://".length] isEqualToString:@"http://"])
    str = [str substringFromIndex:@"http://".length];
```

That would be more robust and will actually make sure it starts with "http://" and not replace every instance of it.