# Substring from NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring, substring

I am using `NSString` and I want to get a substring of it that contains the first 20 characters of my string. How can I do that?

Comment: This is way too easily Google-able.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440187/get-substring-from-nsstring,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613591/finding-a-substring-in-a-nsstring-object, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676106/how-to-get-substring-of-nsstring

Comment: for get particular 20 characters from some stating characters to some last characters then check my this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415776/extract-substring-from-nsstring/13415868#13415868

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use `substringToIndex`.

```
NSString *mystring = @"This is a test message having more than 20 characters";
NSString *newString = [mystring substringToIndex:20];
NSLog(@"%@", newString);
```

Comment: actually it is a good practice that you check the string length before substring
NSString *newString = myString.length > 20 ? [mystring substringToIndex:20] : myString;

Answer (score 35):

```
NSString *str = @"123456789012345678901234";
NSString *subStr = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 20)];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *string = @"I am having a simple question.I am having NSString and i want a substring of it that contains first 20 ";
NSString *first20CharString = [string substringToIndex:20];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSString *string = @"This is for testing substring from string";
    NSInteger intIndex = 20;
    NSLog(@"%@", [string substringToIndex:intIndex]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check with below:

```
NSString *strTmp = @"This is test string to check substring.";
NSInteger intIdx = 20;
NSLog(@"%@", [strTmp substringToIndex:intIdx]);
```

It will be helpful to you.

Cheers!