# How to get sub string from main string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to get expires value.

```
NString *string = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX5fQeRXh3-cas&expires=0998"
```

But i required output : 0998

Comment: What you have tried??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14767167/substring-from-nsstring

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676106/how-to-get-substring-of-nsstring

Comment: @user3559963.. It's very easy to search this stuff on web. So first try to salve it on your self then if can't find much then ask a SO question.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *arr=[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"&expires="];
```

And then `[arr objectAtIndex:1]` will be the required expires value.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
NSString *string = @"XXXXXXXXXXXXXX5fQeRXh3-cas&expires=0998";
NSRange r = [string rangeOfString:@"expires="];
NSString *expStr = [string substringFromIndex:r.location+r.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [NSString](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a) method [rangeOfString](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/rangeOfString%3a):